# Getting SQL Server to perform a stored proc based on a timer?

Tags: sql-server

I'm not a DBA by any means, but i need my SQL Server to perform "checks" everyday (say at midnight)

They're pretty simple (I think), e.g. - if a particular row's dateTime has passed, I'd like to delete that row and set the column in the reference table to NULL

Is this a database trigger?

Any sample code or links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? (2000/2005/2008). And are you on an express edition?

Comment: Triggers operate whenever code is added, updated or deleted (or when the schema itself is changed in newer versions). You canot control the time when a trigger will kick off making this inappropriate for your task.

Answer (score 4):

You would typically use a [SQL Server Agent Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739.aspx) for this. Unless you are on an express edition where this is not available?

For express editions you could either [use the windows task scheduler](http://lunarmedia.com/blogs/lunarmedia_blog/archive/2008/02/04/running-a-stored-procedure-from-windows-task-scheduler.aspx) or perhaps look at the [workaround approach](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scheduling-jobs-in-sql-server-express) here using Service Broker.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Maintenance Plan (or SQL Agent Job, as Martin said):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187658.aspx

(Assuming your MS-SQL server is new enough to support that)

Otherwise, you can use Task Scheduler in the Windows system to create a scheduled task that will do what you want.